# Wrong Architecture when running executable from Xcode4 on UNIX

Tags: unix, xcode4, terminal

First of all, I'm very new to programming.

1. I have a build a program using Xcode 4 on Snow Leopard. 
   Architecture of the project is set to "Standard (32/64-bit intel)"
2. Afterwards I have exported the executable file to a UNIX computer for running.
3. ssh to that computer
4. Typing `./programname` in the terminal (Of the UNIX computer) gives the following response: 
   Exec format error. Wrong Architecture.

The program runs just fine on my Mac laptop.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile a program it will (<sup>*</sup>) be compiled for **a specific platform** and **a specific operating system**. It will also most likely be compiled against a specific set of libraries. *Usually* those parameters are exactly those of the computer doing the compilation (the other cases are called cross-compilation).

In other words: compiling a program on a Mac will produce a binary that runs **only** on a Mac (unless, again, you're doing cross-compilation). Your UNIX system (which UNIX, by the way?) has a different operating system, different libraries and probably even a different CPU architetcture.

Somewhat related: Apples advertised (or used to advertise) Mac OS X as a UNIX. While Mac OS X is certainly a UNIX-class operating system, that **doesn't** mean that it's binary compatible with every other UNIX-class OS out there.

<sup>* almost always, with the exception of systems designed to avoid this (e.g. Java)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Programs compiled by XCode will only run under MacOS X.  Unless the "UNIX computer" in step 2 is running MacOS, the program will not be able to run.